# Ubuntu automount behavior

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount

This one's part anecdote, party question:
I just recently got Ubuntu 9.10 running on a box I plan to use as a build server.  I've been working with a system that's booting off an SD card lately, so my build process is normally make a change, mount SD card, copy new boot image, unmount SD card, put card in system, boot.  Obviously, this requires a lot of mounting an unmounting of media drives as my development process goes on.  I eventually plan to run my build server headless, so for now I've got my monitor attached to a KVM switch which in turn is attached to my build server and my workstation, and I've been doing most of my work on my workstation, ssh'd into my build server.

I noticed that as time went on, my build server started to really slow down.  I flipped my KVM switch to take a look at it and realized, with much surprise, that Ubuntu had opened up a new window for every time that I had mounted my SD card.  As I hadn't had my monitor flipped to my build server for about a week, I had somewhere in the range of 50 windows open on the desktop, all with errors about that location no longer existing.

Fun times.

Now for the question:  How do I go about changing Ubuntu's media automount behavior?  I like that my SD card is being mounted each time I plug it in, but I want to disable its default behavior of opening the media in a file explorer each time it mounts.  Unfortunately, trying to type Ubuntu mount behavior or ubuntu automount windows into google gives very misleading results.  Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this](http://tips4linux.com/disable-automount-for-removable-devices-in-ubuntu/) page:

Alternatively, if you only want to disable the Nautilus window that opens up every time you plug in a storage device, the simpler method for this is to open up Nautilus, go to Edit > Preferences > Media and turn off Browse media when inserted.